# How to get a localized date format for EditText hint in android

Tags: java, android, localization, date-format

How to get a localized date format for an EditText hint in android?

```
yyyy-mm-dd(EN)
aaaa-mm-dd(SP)
aaaa-mm-jj(FR)
```

Comment: But android.util.Log - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateFormat.getDateFormat(Context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat(android.content.Context)), which does the following:

> Returns a `DateFormat` object that can format the date in short form (such as 12/31/1999) according to the current locale and the user's date-order preference.
>
> -- [`DateFormat` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)

Then, pass to it an object of type `Activity` or `Context`:

```
java.text.DateFormat formatter = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
```

Comment: but I need to get a localized date format, not to convert... .

Comment: You can print out the format as a String, just as you did before in your example.

Comment: it's not properly working. for exemple it prints "M/d/yy" with Locale.ENGLISH and "dd/MM/y" for Locale.FRENCH

Answer (score 1):

From [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat(String, Locale)
```

> Constructs a new SimpleDateFormat using the specified non-localized pattern and the DateFormatSymbols and Calendar for the specified locale.

So the pattern should not change

[DateFormatSymbols](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)

> Encapsulates localized date-time formatting data, such as the names of the months, the names of the days of the week, and the time zone data. DateFormat and SimpleDateFormat both use DateFormatSymbols to encapsulate this information.

The only thing that should change is month name, tzdata or day of week name if you'd used any.

For getting a localized pattern String use

```
toLocalizedPattern()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern%28%29

Comment: ok, my proposal is not correct (I've edited the question), but how to get yyyy-mm-dd(EN)
aaaa-mm-dd(SP)
aaaa-mm-jj(FR)?

Comment: What do you mean aaaa? 'a' is an AM/PM marker. And what is 'j'? Does 2013-02-12 have to look different in different countries?

Comment: I need to get a date format for hint. In english: D(ay)/M(onth)/Y(ear)

Comment: Sorry. Finally I got it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `SimpleDateFormat.applyLocalizedPattern(String template)` before calling `SimpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(mContext);

String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();

editText.setHint(pattern);
```